# RecycleView/CardView data set update

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-5.0-lollipop, android-cardview

I am currently trying to update a `RecyclerView` once an `AsyncTask` has completed its operation.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initializing RecycleView
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    mAdapter = new AdvertAdapter(this.results, R.layout.card_advert, this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Here is a code snippet from my `AsyncTask`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        // your stuff
        listener.onTaskCompleted(data);
    }
```

In the listener Activity class, I am updating the data set and attempting to notify my custom adapter that the data set has been changed:

```
@Override
public void onTaskCompleted(ArrayList<Data>results) {
    this.results = results;
    this.mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    System.out.println("Done.");
}
```

It seems that `notifyDataSetChanged()` is not actually doing anything, as the list remains empty even after the final line. From the debugger, I can verify that results does contain the correct results, and the `onTaskCompleted` is being run on the main thread. How can I update my `RecyclerView` with the new results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add the `ArrayList<Data>results` to your adapter data.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onTaskCompleted(ArrayList<Data>results) {
    //this.results = results;

    this.mAdapter.clear();
    this.mAdapter.add(results);
    //or this.mAdapter.results = results;

    this.mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    System.out.println("Done.");
}
```

Comment: If I am updating a specific Recycler item does the above apply but use "this.mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition())"? or "this,mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position)" where position = getAdapterPosition()?